# Automatic parameter search for a given output in LTSpice

Tags: simulation, spice, software, ltspice

I am simulating a circuit on LTSpice and was wondering if there is a way to set output parameters for LT to aim for by adjusting values of other components. I have used some software in the past that does this but i cannot remember if it was LTSpice or something else.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

What Daniel says is correct and applies to all SPICEs unless they are seriously enhanced. However what you can do is to vary some sensible design parameters [using `.step param`](http://www.linear.com/solutions/1831) and see how the output changes. But it won't design an optimal circuit for you by itself. There are some hacks using SPICE in a feedback loop, i.e. driving it by some other external program to do a guided optimization. Without knowing what you're trying to do, I'm not gonna get into that.

---

It turns out most [non-free] commercial SPICEs actually do offer some add-on or built-in optimizer. Below I tried to include links to examples with each so you can get some idea; generally these commercial SPICE don't have on-line documentation accessible unless you're paying customer, so precise capabilities are little hard to ascertain beforehand.

- Synopsys HSPICE: [fairly old examples](http://www.ece.uci.edu/docs/hspice/hspice_2001_2-87.html) found on-line.
- Silvaco SmartSpice: [slides from a training](http://www.silvaco.com/content/training/smartspice_training_part4.pdf).
- Mentor Graphics Eldo: [whitepaper](https://www.mentor.com/products/ic_nanometer_design/resources/overview/an-optimizer-assisted-design-methodology-for-a-two-stage-wideband-feedback-amplifier-188418a5-3a28-44a0-a726-3ee2f90c7ce0) that requires registration to read.
- and even [IsSpice4](http://www.intusoft.com/script/optimize.htm) or [TINA](http://www.tina.com/optimization) (not the free TI version though) have something.
- Keysight's ADS Spice module has some capabilities listed in [this blurb](http://www.keysight.com/main/editorial.jspx?cc=US&lc=eng&ckey=2061837&nid=-34333.870778&id=2061837), but I could only find on-line examples (that didn't require customer log-in) for their for their [Momentum EM optimizer](http://edadocs.software.keysight.com/display/ads2008U1/Optimization+of+A+Microstrip+Line).
- Cadence [PSpice](http://www.orcad.com/resources/library/pspice-optimizer) and Spectre (SPICE-alike) each have their own optimizer. The one for PSpice is included only in the Designer Plus version.
- OPUS SPICE is the only free one that seem to have such features, but they are [pretty extensive](http://fides.fe.uni-lj.si/spice/optimize.html); also [paper about them](http://www.spiceopus.si/download/Eurocon07.pdf). (OPUS is kinda kludgy to use for other purposes, in my opinion.)

Since the optimization function[s] are not part of Berkeley SPICE, you should expect a fair amount of differences between these, so evaluate before you buy if you can.

As a separate optimizer that runs on top of other SPICEs, ASCO seems [pretty capable](http://asco.sourceforge.net/examples.html)... and it's also free; It can run with LTspice, ngspice and with some of the non-free commercial ones (Eldo, HSPICE, Spectre). Also, Qucs [uses ASCO](http://gnu-darwin.org/www001/ports-1.5a-CURRENT/cad/qucs/work/qucs-0.0.12/qucs-help/docs/en/start_opt.html) for optimization.

Comment: lol SPICE in a feedback loop. I got to try that sometime. Have you had success or just heard/read about it ?

Comment: @efox29: not with LTspice. Needs something that's command-line based.

Comment: http://hackaday.com/2012/07/09/on-not-designing-circuits-with-evolutionary-algorithms/

Comment: Keysight's ads offers substantial optimization capabilities. I'd guess that HSPICE would also, but I don't use HSPICE.

Comment: Also, LTSpice can be run from the command line.

Comment: Is there any goal seek software?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any way to get LTSpice to goal-seek. While you can do some pretty complicated things with directives (like monte-carlo analyses!) it's still just a simulator not an optimizer.

Comment: Monte-Carlo [is for masochists only](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/137934/parts-tolerance-simulations-in-ltspice) in LTspice...